# How to access the value of the key inside the Jsonfile with for loop

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, filesystems

I am trying to reach username in this for loop. I want to compare username in the request with username in the file. In the for loop i wrote below, I reach the key  for ***""(let user in users)"*** this  ***"1580996730372"*** key. What do I need to do to access the username inside the file. i have tried Object.values() and Object.keys() but maybe i am doing w

### FOR LOOP

```
    let users = JSON.parse(data);

    for (let user in users) {
       if (JSON.stringify(users[user]) === JSON.stringify(req.body)) {
         res.status(200).send({ [user]: users[user] });
       return;
    }
```

### JSON DATA

```
    {
    "1580996730372": {
        "id": "f08dbc40-48e6-11ea-bbe9-c762eb24fe1f",
        "username": "D",
        "password": "kkk333"
    },
    "1580996733810": {
        "id": "f29a5520-48e6-11ea-b91e-fb39bf5103d1",
        "username": "Dskskk",
        "password": "kkk333"
    },
    "1581009019213": {
        "id": "8d460fd0-4903-11ea-9b24-1bb0f34ace07",
        "username": "Dkdkd",
        "password": "vvvkxkkffkk748484"
    },
    "1581009170013": {
        "id": "e72850d0-4903-11ea-ae92-c3bd48f3469a",
        "username": "Dkdkdjjj",
        "password": "hhjh7666"
    },
    "1581068163542": {
        "id": "420a7760-498d-11ea-b90d-4d96b87b7fc1",
        "username": "İbotest",
        "password": "skskkssk377338"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `user` is a value like `"1580996730372"` then

- `users[user]` represents the object whose key is `"1580996730372"`
- `users[user]['username']` is the value of the `username` key